# Simplify the following expressions where $A. B, C$ represents matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi I'm currently doing a linear algebra assignment and I was wondering if anyone could reassure me if I'm right or help if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance!

$$\begin{align}AB(BC-CB)+(CA-AB)BC+CA(A-B)C = &ABBC-ABCB+CABC-ABBC+CAAB-CABC &\\= & -ABCB+CAAB &\\= & -AB^2C+A^2BC\end{align}$$

Comment: It should be $ABBC-ABCB+CABC-ABBC+CAA\color{red}{C}-CABC.$ On the other hand $ABCB\ne AB^2C$ in general.

Comment: @mfl Oh thanks, I didn't even notice that mistake. And so I should just remove the last step?

Comment: For general matrices $-ABCB+CAAC$ can not be simplied. The most you can do is write $CA^2C-ABCB.$ But $CA^2C\ne C^2A^2$ in general. (Note that the product of matrices is not commutative.)

Comment: @mfl All better? & Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @TaljanaD Did you correct the equation in the question after mfl pointed out the mistakes ?

Comment: @A---B Oops! I did on my assignment but not on here, thank you!

Comment: @TaljanaD It looks like it is other way around. The equations before my edit doesn't match the source of the question which contained errors. Just look, maybe you didn't change the assignment :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
AB(BC-CB)+(CA-AB)BC+CA(A-B)C  \\
=ABBC-ABCB+CABC-ABBC+CAA\color{red}{C}-CABC \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
The first and fourth terms will cancel & the third and sixth terms cancel & we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
=-ABCB+CAAC. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that you cannot reorder the multiplications in each of these terms.